# Wrap text around R plot figure in knitr

Tags: wrapfigure, knitr, wrap

How can I make the text wrap around a figure produced by R code in knitr?

I have tried the following:

1. as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34017777/wrapping-figure-with-latex-environment-in-knitr-rmarkdown-with-hooks), adding

   ```
   knit_hooks$set(wrapf = function(before, options, envir) {
     if(before) {
       "\\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\\textwidth}"
     } else {
       "\\end{wrapfigure}"
     }
   })
   ```

   to a chunk of R code and using `wrapf=TRUE` for the chunk with the plot.
2. Set the option `fig.env` to either 'wrapfigure' or 'marginfigure' (and with a non-empty `fig.cap`). The document does not compile with either option (but does if neither is used).

Comment: Could you please add MWE, http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that